# How do I "watch" a unix socket to see what requests are coming through?

Tags: nginx, web-server, http, socket

My nginx is forwarding its incoming http web requests to a local unix socket (`unix:/var/run/foo.sock`). On the other end I have a separate web server (puma + ruby on rails, if it matters) reading from that websocket.

For debugging purposes, is there a way to "see" what my web server sees? In other words, can I read incoming traffic from that same socket to verify whether a request is coming through properly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are several apps: netcat or socat amongst others to read/write data from/to sockets.

For example:

```
nc -lU pathtosocket
```

For exact syntax check the manual of the program as there are several variations of netcat.

Comment: Thanks! Could you provide an example of using `netcat` here ?